# EditText Click not working

Tags: android, click, android-edittext

I am going through a problem .

**XML Coding**

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edt_txt_id"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:focusable="false"
   android:onClick="editTextClick" >
</EditText>
```

**Java Coding**

```
public void editTextClick(View v) {

     if (v.getId() == R.id.edt_txt_id){

        System.out.println(" edit text click");
        EditText edtxtx =(EditText)v;
        edtxtx.requestFocus();
        edtxtx.setText("");

       }
}
```

I want that when i click on editText then current text must be dissapperar. But when i click with

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Click event work fine but cursor is no longer at Edit-text. It means if want to enter some new Text then how could enter this new text even cursor is not at Edit-text , and if i work with

```
android:focusable="true"
```

then click event does not work. But is available for any new edit .What is problem ? I know it is silly mistake , but where , i can't figure out.Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: I think first time I saw that someone have implemented onClick Listener for EditText. By the way What you are trying to do? You should use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
public void editTextClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.edt_txt_id) {
            System.out.println(" edit text click");
            EditText edtxtx = (EditText) v;

            edtxtx.setFocusable(true); // Add This Line And try

            edtxtx.requestFocus();
            edtxtx.setText("");

        }
    }
```

Comment: do you want to implement kind of hint functionality?

Comment: Actually this is for Custom BaseAdpter. Click event in my main Activity , in my App it contain lot of clickevent in custom dialog so i defined all these in single method in my mainActivity. I am going through this problem from last two days , at last i post this thread. Please help me to get me out of this issue.

Comment: Without  android:focusable="......" , program execution is not entering in if{  } block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `setonFocusChange` listener for your `EditText` to achieve the functionality which you want.

Here is the focus listener example.

```
edtxtx.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           edtxtx.setText("");
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , but as i told i can't handle it in your way , i am using custom BaseAdater and i declare it as setter-getter . Click event in mainActivity . If i used as per your suggestion i am getting NullPointer Exception , because edt_xtx is not declare in my mainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was asked long back, thought my answer would help someone. I faced the same issue that editText was not focusing on click.

I had the below code to my EditText's parent layout which was blocking the keyboard.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Remove this and try it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the text

change  `edtxtx.getText("");`to

```
edtxtx.setText("");
```

Comment: Sorry it is setText(""), it is my typeing mistake.

Comment: But this is not my main issue.If you could help me to resolve in my main issue then i will be glad

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void editTextClick(View v) {
     if (v.getId() == R.id.edt_txt_id){
        System.out.println(" edit text click");
        EditText edtxtx =(EditText)v;
        edtxtx.setFocusable(true);
        edtxtx.setText("");

     }}
```

After this again `setFocusable(false);` So that it can take click event again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `android:focusable="false"` in xml ... write this in your code on `onCreate()` :

```
    if (EditText.hasFocus()) {
        EditText.clearFocus();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this attrs in your `Edittext`:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```